# C# resource file with Japanese characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, resources

I am reading some Japanese characters out of a resource file for my UI strings. I manually added them to the resource file. They look ok in the resource file and even if I open the resource file with Notepad++. But when I ready them into my variables, they turn into question marks. I know I need to use UTF8 encoding, but where?

I am also reading strings out of an external file (non-resource) and the UTF8 encoding works just fine there.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the culture property in the resx file. How do I change it from "neutral" to "Japanese"(or whatever is needed)?

this works (reading from a regular file):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputxliff))
        {
            data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        inputxliff.Close();
        string filetag = "<file original";
        int mycount = (data.Length - data.Replace(filetag, "").Length) / filetag.Length;
        string header = getBetween(data, "<?", "<file", true, false);
        byte[] bheader = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
```

This does NOT work (reading from resx file, actually it works fine for ENU and DEU but not for JPN):

```
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(mypath + "\\ResourcesJPN.resx"))
        {
            string instructions = resxSet.GetString("instructions");
            byte[] instrBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(instructions);
            string myinstructions = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(instrBytes);
```

I'd love any suggestions.

Comment: Is the resx not part of your project? I'm able to use `MyResx.Key` just fine to populate Japanese characters to a winform...

Comment: File name for resources is Name.culture.resx, eg: Resources.ja-jp.resx, have you check that?

Comment: I think you should look at this for specific language resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992030(v=vs.100).aspx. The naming convention should follow `[resource_name].[ISO_culture_code].resx`.